# GRPC with Angular and Typescript

Tags: angularjs, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web, python-envoy

I have a GRPC service running written in Python. I have the python support proto file for the same.

I want to integrate this backend with AngularJS+Typescript UI.

Questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. Do I have to change anything in the Python grpc server end?
3. I checked online and it seems Envoy help in doing similar thing, is Envoy the only solution? As I tried a lot and its not working.
4. What all changes are required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gRPC support javascript, you don't need to modify the server, just use service proto generate client javascript files, and use typescript call the function. You need add the [grpc-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) to your client project. Envoy is not necessary for request server.

Comment: "Envoy is not necessary for request server"; can you please provide further information on this? The [grpc-Web readme](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) states "gRPC-web clients connect to gRPC services via a special proxy; by default, gRPC-web uses Envoy" so, as I understand it, Envoy (or [an alternative](https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/tree/master/go/grpcwebproxy)) is still needed with Python (to translate between gRPC-Web and gRPC)? (I'm aware there are [python-first gRPC-Web implementations](https://github.com/public/sonora) but the OP did not mention using one).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate gRPC API's with angular(typescript).

follow [**here**](https://intuting.medium.com/using-protocol-buffers-in-angular-96b4f8ab18d4) it will helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33123632)